# Handling Update State Multiple Switch in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

**Description**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have a table with many rows, each row of table data has a switch form. The code I sent only creates one object even though I clicked on the switch in the second row, which means the data is being overridden. My expectation is that when I click on a new row, a new state object will be added. Here are the initial state, handler, and mutation:

State :

```
const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState({
  add: true,
  modify: true,
  delete: true,
  view: true,
  export: true,
  permission: "",
});
```

Handler :

```
const onCheckboxChange = (event, permission) => {
  setCheckedValues({
   ...checkedValues,
   [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
   permission: permission,
  });
};
```

Mutation :

```
  const assignPermissionPromise = assignPermission({
        variables: {
          input: {
            groupId: groupId,
            permissionCodes: [
              {
                add: checkedValues.add,
                modify: checkedValues.modify,
                export: checkedValues.export,
                delete: checkedValues.delete,
                view: checkedValues.view,
                permission: checkedValues.permission,
              }
            ],
          },
        },
      });
```

There is also a component that need to change the way to get the checkbox update value:

```
<>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`lihat-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="view"
        defaultChecked={checked.view}
        value={checked.view}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`tambah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="add"
        defaultChecked={checked.add}
        value={checked.add}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`ubah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="modify"
        defaultChecked={checked.modify}
        value={checked.modify}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`hapus-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="delete"
        defaultChecked={checked.delete}
        value={checked.delete}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`export-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="export"
        defaultChecked={checked.export}
        value={checked.export}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
  </>
```

**Expected Output**

The expected output is that when I click on the second row or apply multiple role permissions, the number of objects placed into an array should increase. Example:

```
[
    {
      add: true,
      modify: true,
      delete: true,
      view: true,
      export: true,
      permission: "user",
    },
    {
      add: true,
      modify: true,
      delete: true,
      view: true,
      export: true,
      permission: "user_group",
    },
]
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank You.

Full Source Code.

formKontroldanHakAksesTambah.js (parent)

```
const FormKontrolDanHakAksesTambah = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Tambah Group Role";
  }, []);

  // state for input form group and switches
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    groupId: "",
    groupName: "",
    groupDesc: "",
  });

  const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState(
    {
      add: true,
      modify: true,
      delete: true,
      view: true,
      export: true,
      permission: "",
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checkedValues);
  }, [checkedValues]);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue({
      ...value,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const onCheckboxChange = (event, permission) => {
    setCheckedValues({
      ...checkedValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
      permission: permission
    });
  };
  
  const [createUserGroup, { loading: loadingCreateUserGroup }] = useMutation(
    CREATE_USER_GROUP,
    {
      onCompleted: () => {
        history.push("/konfigurasi/grup-dan-hak-akses-pengguna");
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.error(err.message);
      },
    }
  );

  const [assignPermission, { loading: assignPermsLoading }] = useMutation(
    ASSIGN_PERMS,
    {
      onError: (err) => {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        console.log(assignPermission);
      },
    }
  );

  if (loadingCreateUserGroup || assignPermsLoading)
    return (
      <>
        <Loading />
      </>
    );

  const handleSubmitGroupBaru = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      value.groupId === "" ||
      value.groupName === "" ||
      value.groupDesc === ""
    ) {
      // Menampilkan pesan error jika ada field yang kosong
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Silakan lengkapi semua field",
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Membuat promise untuk mutasi createUserGroup
      const createGroupPromise = createUserGroup({
        variables: {
          input: {
            groupId: value.groupId,
            groupName: value.groupName,
            groupDesc: value.groupDesc,
          },
        },
        awaitRefetchQueries: true,
        refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_ALL_USER_GROUP }, "getAllUserGroup"],
      });

      // Menunggu hasil promise mutasi createUserGroup
      const {
        data: {
          createUserGroup: { groupId },
        },
      } = await createGroupPromise;

      // Membuat promise untuk mutasi assignPermission
      const assignPermissionPromise = assignPermission({
        variables: {
          input: {
            groupId: groupId,
            permissionCodes: [
              {
                add: checkedValues.add,
                modify: checkedValues.modify,
                export: checkedValues.export,
                delete: checkedValues.delete,
                view: checkedValues.view,
                permission: checkedValues.permission,
              }
            ],
          },
        },
      });

      // Menunggu hasil promise mutasi assignPermission
      await assignPermissionPromise;

      Swal.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: "Akun Grup berhasil ditambahkan",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: err.message,
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className={`${styles.FormAksi}`}>
        <Container className={`${styles.container}`}>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card className={`${styles.customCard}`}>
                <Card.Title className={`${styles.customCardHeader}`}>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold">
                    Informasi Grup Akun
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  <FormCreateGroup onChange={onChange} value={value} />
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <Card className="border-0 mt-5">
                <Card.Title>
                  <p className="text-uppercase base-lg text-semi-bold mt-2 mx-2">
                    Kontrol Akses
                  </p>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  <TableRole
                    checkedValues={checkedValues}
                    onChange={onCheckboxChange}
                  />
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>

        <Divider className="my-3" />

        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <ButtonSecondary
            variant="solid"
            wider="true"
            onClick={handleSubmitGroupBaru}
            className="mt-5"
          >
            {" "}
            <FaSave className="mx-2" /> SIMPAN PERUBAHAN
          </ButtonSecondary>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

TableRole.js (child)

```
export default function TableRole({ checkedValues, onChange }) {
  const tableHeader = [
    "No",
    "Menu",
    "Sub Menu",
    "Lihat",
    "Tambah",
    "Ubah",
    "Hapus",
    "Export",
  ];

  const tableData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      menu: "Dashboard",
      submenu: ["-"],

    },
    {
      id: 2,
      menu: "Konfigurasi/Pengaturan",
      submenu: [
        {
          name: 'Akun Pengguna',
          permission: 'user',
          permissionIndex: 1,
        },
        {
          name: 'Grup',
          permission: 'user_group',
          permissionIndex: 2
        }
     ]
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Table className="table-responsive">
      <thead
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEFF1" }}
        className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold"
      >
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="text-center">
        {tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <React.Fragment key={rowIndex}>
            <RoleRow
              index={rowIndex + 1}
              menu={row.menu}
              submenu={row.submenu}
              checked={checkedValues}
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}

const RoleRow = ({ index, menu, submenu ,checked,onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td rowSpan={submenu.length + 1}>{index}</td>
        <td rowSpan={submenu.length + 1}>{menu}</td>
      </tr>
      {submenu.map((subMenuItem, subMenuItemIndex) => (
        <tr key={`${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}-${subMenuItem.permission}`}>
          <td>{subMenuItem.name}</td>  
          <PermissionCheckbox
              checked={checked[subMenuItemIndex]}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e, subMenuItem.permission, index)}
          />
        </tr>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const PermissionCheckbox = ({ index, subMenuItemIndex, checked, onChange, perms }) => (
  <>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`lihat-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="view"
        defaultChecked={checked.view}
        value={checked.view}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`tambah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="add"
        defaultChecked={checked.add}
        value={checked.add}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`ubah-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="modify"
        defaultChecked={checked.modify}
        value={checked.modify}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`hapus-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="delete"
        defaultChecked={checked.delete}
        value={checked.delete}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
    <td>
      <Form.Check
        id={`export-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
        type="switch"
        name="export"
        defaultChecked={checked.export}
        value={checked.export}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </td>
  </>
);
```

here's the codesandbox demo :

https://codesandbox.io/s/test-checkbox-40tm39?file=/src/App.js:392-410
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMHUm.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `checkedValues` is an object. So it is getting overwritten every time switch is clicked. I would suggest create an array for `checkedValues`, then update the individual object of `checkedValues`. Similar like this,

```
const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState([]);

const onCheckboxChange = (event, permission) => {
  setCheckedValues((prevState) => [
    ...prevState,
    {
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
      permission: permission,
    },
  ]);
};
```

In the `assignPermission` mutation,

```
const assignPermissionPromise = assignPermission({
  variables: {
    input: {
      groupId: groupId,
      permissionCodes: checkedValues.map((checkedValue) => ({
        add: checkedValue.add,
        modify: checkedValue.modify,
        export: checkedValue.export,
        delete: checkedValue.delete,
        view: checkedValue.view,
        permission: checkedValue.permission,
      })),
    },
  },
});
```

In the `Form.Check` component, pass the permission string as a prop:

```
<Form.Check
  id={`lihat-${index}-${subMenuItemIndex}`}
  type="switch"
  name="view"
  defaultChecked={checked.view}
  value={checked.view}
  onChange={(event) =>
    onCheckboxChange(event, "permission string")
  }
/>
```

Comment: how can i get the update value checkedValues from the switch component sir ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Checkout

Comment: i think, your previous answer about handler that's work for me. but i am confuse how to get update value checkedValues.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox demo?

Comment: done sir, question has edited